Worker logs are trimmed in locustUI
I'm running locust in distributed node with logs.

The worker attempted to send more than 10 log lines in one interval. Further log sending was disabled for this worker.

The worker logs do not land after this exception, is there a way to override this behavior?
The code doing this is in runners.py:
def logs_reporter(self) -> None:
    if WORKER_LOG_REPORT_INTERVAL < 0:
        return

    while True:
        current_logs = get_logs()

        if (len(current_logs) - len(self.logs)) > 10:
            logger.warning(
                "The worker attempted to send more than 10 log lines in one interval. Further log sending was disabled for this worker."
            )
            self._send_logs(get_logs())
            break
        if len(current_logs) > len(self.logs):
            self._send_logs(current_logs)

        self.logs = current_logs
        gevent.sleep(WORKER_LOG_REPORT_INTERVAL)


Not really, this is to protect the master. But the logs are still available on the worker terminal. As a workaround you could change WORKER_LOG_REPORT_INTERVAL to a lower value.
